# Which << is my overloaded operator in this statement?

Tags: c++

I have an overloaded << operator from my reckful class implemented as follows:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const reckful& p)
{
    os << p.PrintStuff();

    return os;
}
```

PrintStuff() just being a member function of reckful that returns a string.

The way I understand things, if I were to write something like `cout << reckobject << endl;` in main(), `cout << reckobject` would take precedence and my overloaded << (using cout as the left operand and reckobject as the right operand) would return the ostream object `os`, leaving the expression `os << endl;` to be evaluated which would output the string and then end the line. So, the first << is the one I declared and the second is the standard << right?

However, my main question is... what is the sequence of events, which are the left and right operands, and which << operators are which when I run a statement like this:

```
cout << "reckful object = " << reckobject << "!" << endl;
```

Why does this work if there isn't an ostream object and a reckful object on either side of one << ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you notice standard way to implement `<<` it returns the ostream itself. This is the critical piece

So something like

```
 cout << "reckful object = " << reckobject << "!" << endl;
```

will be called once for

```
cout << "reckful object = "
```

This function call will return a `ostream` with which the second call will be made

namely

```
   cout  << reckobject;
```

so on an so forth.

You can test is out by implementing your `<<` as

```
void operator << (ostream& os, const reckful& p)
{  
    os << 1;
}
```

in which case you can do

```
std::cout << p;
```

**but not**

```
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

The operators make it harder to understand but consider this `Point` class

```
struct Point
{
    Point& setX( int x) { X = x; return *this;}
    Point& setY( int y) { Y = y; return *this;}

    int X;
    int Y;
};
```

The way `setX` and `setY` are defined, allows

```
    Point p;
    p.setX( 2 ).setY( 4 );
```

This is the same mechanism `<<` is using to chain function calls.

Answer (score 3):

Because each `<<` returns a reference to `cout`. Because the operator `<<` is left-associative, the calls are done from left to right, so

```
a << b << c
```

is equivalent to

```
(a << b) << c
```

which is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to

```
operator<<(operator<<(a, b), c);
```

So in your example, you are doing

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, "reckful object = "), reckobject), "!"), endl);
```

As you can see, each `<<` depends on the return value of the previous `<<` (or just `cout` in case there is no further left `<<`). If you change one of the return types of the `<<`s to `void`, you effectively stop any more `<<` calls, because `void` can't be used as an argument to a function.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's not exactly equivalent because in that example, all `operator<<` are free functions, whereas in reality, some can be member functions, so you could have a mix of member and non-member calls like

```
operator<<(a, b).operator<<(c);
```

or

```
operator<<(a.operator<<(b), c);
```